# Generating list of tuples using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I have a function which takes as an argument list of tuples representing column name and it's type. Based on the list passed, I need to generate another list of tuples, this time containing data from spreadsheet. Each row should have information from all the columns covered in columns tuple.

How can I generate list of tuples with data using list comprehension?

I came up with this code:

```
# Validate the index range if provided
if index_range is not None:
    if not isinstance(index_range, tuple):
        raise ValueError(f"index_range provided is of type {type(index_range)} not tuple")
    elif len(index_range) != 2:
        raise ValueError(f"index_range provided has length {len(index_range)} but should have length 2")
    elif type(index_range[0]) is not int:
        raise ValueError(f"Start index in index_range is type {type(index_range[0])} but should be int")
    elif type(index_range[1]) is not int:
        raise ValueError(f"End index in index_range is type {type(index_range[0])} but should be int")
    elif index_range[1] < index_range[0]:
        raise ValueError(f"End index in index_range is {index_range[1]} and start index is {index_range[0]}. "
                         f"End index cannot be lower than start index")

# Read the 'data' workbook from this file
excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(path)
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, 'data')

# Tuples list instance
list_tuples = list()

# Determine the indexes
if index_range is not None:
    start_index = index_range[0]
    end_index = index_range[1] + 1
else:
    start_index = 0
    end_index = df[df.columns[0]].count()

# Iterate through the results and insert data tuples into the list
for i in range(start_index, end_index):
    try:
        list_tuples.append(tuple(
            [convert_to(df.loc[i, el[0]], el[1]) for el in clmns]
        ))
    except Exception as ex:
        log.log_error(f"[{df.loc[i, clmns[0]]}] {str(ex)}", True)
        if is_test:
            list_tuples.append((
                df.loc[i, clmns[0]], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None
            ))

# Check if there were results and finish
if len(list_tuples) > 0:
    to_call(list_tuples, is_test)
else:
    log.log_info('There are no results from Excel')
```

`el[0]` is column name and `el[1]` is the desired type. It works OK for the first row, but even when start index is 0 and end index is 10, the main for loop generates only one tuple and then breaks...

`convert_to`:

```
if pd.isna(obj):
        return None
    elif as_type is None or obj is None:
        return obj
    else:
        return as_type(obj)
```

Comment: What does "breaks" mean? What happens? Is there an error? If so, please [edit] your post and add its [*full text*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146). What is your input, and what output, if any, do you get from it? Please make your question a [mre].

Comment: Where is the definition for `convert_to`?

Comment: @MattDMo "Breaks" means after first iteration it jumps out of the loop, even if start_index is 0 and end_index is 10. The input is, as mentioned above, is a list of tuples with column names. The output should be list of rows with data from columns specified in input, read from Pandas dataframe.

Comment: @Ave319, `convert_to` converts the data to desired type, unless the desired type is None. It's not relevant here, sorry just copied the whole loop code.

Comment: `[convert_to(df.loc[i, el[0]], el[1]) for el in columns]` this is almost certainly not what but without seeing the rest of your code it's impossible for us to tell. Assuming `columns` is an iterable of `DataFrame` column names, e.g. `['Test1', 'Test2']` then `el[0]` will simply be `'T'`, or the first letter of each column name. Your `except Exception as ex:` is hiding the `KeyError` that it would typically raise.

Comment: I'm running this in debug mode, it never jumps to except clause with any error, just exits the loop...

Comment: If you are uncertain of what the problem is, how can you be certain that it's not relevant? Does the problem persist if it's removed? If so, it shouldn't be in your question at all. As @MattDMo already mentioned your question needs an [mre] which we can run by ourselves.

Comment: I just updated the question with full function code. I checked without `convert_to` but result is the same.